# Uncommon Inverse Laplace Transforms

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, laplace-transform, inverse-laplace

I'm interested in calculating inverse Laplace transforms of functions such as

$$\frac{1}{(1-s^{2})\log(s)}, \frac{1}{\operatorname{acosh}\left(1+\frac{s^{2}}{4}\right)}$$

and more exotic examples.

In general reciprocals of some elementary functions on $\mathbb{C}$ with some branches. The first example was $\frac{1}{\sqrt{s^{2}+1}}$ which is solved by Bessel functions.

I'm trying to find some comprehensive tables of Laplace transforms and have found a few small things but it would be nice to find a comprehensive reference. Is there a good place to look for inverse Laplace transforms of this form?

Also if anyone knows the inverse Laplace transform of these expressions above that would also be of great help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For more exotic function,I doubt there's a closed form will be. Only hope is numeric.For first one: $\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{\left(1-s^2\right) \log (s)}\right](t)=\int_0^{\infty } \frac{e^{-t} \left((-t)^{-x} t^x (\Gamma (x)-\Gamma
   (x,-t))+e^{2 t} (-\Gamma (x)+\Gamma (x,t))\right)}{2 \Gamma (x)} \, dx$.A good book: http://www.worldcat.org/title/integrals-and-series-volume-5-inverse-laplace-transforms/oclc/489706146

Comment: Thanks the reference was perfect!